# How can I limit the storage I give each user on an iOS(swift)/Firebase app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I’m making a photo gallery app and want users to have 2GB storage and then pay for more storage

I’ve completed a fair bit of the app but I’m having difficulty on the approach of how to allocate the 2GB and allowing users to unlock extra space

If anyone could give basic directions thatd be great

Answer (score 1):

**Work around**: You should have a variable name like : "used_storage", save it wherever you want. (don't make user easy to change its)

```
max_storage = 2 * 2^20
```

When you save gallery with size x KBs to application document folder:

```
if used_storage + x < max_storage {
  used_storage += x
  // update used_storage
  // save your image
} else {
  // alert to user that they used to much and must charge for more space ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful